# Firebase is storing value even when user deleted it

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am struggling with the problem of storing the data. I am writing app that uses the firebase for authentication and as the database. The application works as scooter sharing. When user taps on one of the markers and taps on reserve button scooter is reserved by sending string value. It goes something like this:

- I am tapping on reserve button
- I am sendnig check value and user ID to selected scooter record as userKey
- I am waiting for server response (feedback)
- If there is response start reservation

If user change their mind and click on cancel button I am clearing the userKey and changing the status from Reserved to Off. 
And there is a problem. 
Even when I clear the userKey in appropriate scooter the function responsible for reservation can be still executed. For example when I simulate the server and I send `feedback` command to previously reserved scooter below code can be still executed even if the `userKey` is empty string. It doesn't happened to scooters that was not reserved yet. The main code goes like this:

```
    func fetchScooters(){


    ref?.child("service").child("scooters").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        if snapshot.exists(){
            let array:NSArray = snapshot.children.allObjects as NSArray

            self.skutery = []

            for child in array{

                let snap = child as! DataSnapshot

                if let dictionary = snap.value as? [String: Any] {

                    let skuter = ScooterInformation()

                    skuter.name = dictionary["name"] as? String
                    skuter.state = dictionary["state"] as? String
                    skuter.latitude = dictionary["latitude"] as? String
                    skuter.longitude = dictionary["longitude"] as? String
                    skuter.battery = dictionary["battery"] as? String
                    skuter.engine = dictionary["engine"] as? String
                    skuter.start = dictionary["start"] as? CLong
                    skuter.userKey = dictionary["userKey"] as? String


                    self.skutery.append(skuter)

                    if skuter.userKey == self.userID{


                        self.hideAllScootersIfUserReserved(scooterInfo: self.skutery)

                        // THERE IS SOMETHING WRONG....

                        self.handle = snap.ref.child("feedback").observe(.value, with: { (feedback) in
                            if let feedback = feedback.value as? Bool{
                                    if feedback && skuter.userKey == self.userID{

                                        print("Feedback received")
                                        self.coundDown.invalidate()
                                        self.timeToConnect = 20
                                        snap.ref.child("feedback").removeValue()
                                        snap.ref.child("check").removeValue()


                                        if self.wantToRunScooter {
                                            self.startScooter()

                                        } else if self.userIsReservedScooter{
                                            self.setStatusAsReserved()
                                            self.userIsReservedScooter = false

                                        }


                                }
                            }


                        })
```

By hitting the cancel button this is executed:

```
 ref?.child("service").child("scooters").child("\(scooterNumber!)").child("state").setValue("*oF&")
 ref?.child("service").child("scooters").child("\(scooterNumber!)").child("userKey").setValue("")
```

The `handle` function can be still executed even if the `skuter.userKey` is not equal to `User ID` because `skuter.userKey` should be empty string.

I am struggling with this second day and have no idea what is wrong with this..

I will be very grateful for any help.

Thanks

Comment: try using `removeValue()` instead

Comment: `ref?.child("service").child("scooters").child("\(scooterNumber!)").child("userKey").removeValue()`

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help. It seems that even when I change the string or remove value `self.handle = snap.ref.child("feedback").observe(.value, with: { (feedback)` can be still executed somehow..

Comment: After removing the value add this `if (self.handle != nil) {
    self.ref?.removeObserverWithHandle(handle)
}`

Comment: That may need some refactoring but you want to remove the observer and restart it when you need it.

Comment: The same... It seems that this `self.handle` can be executed when the `if` condition was at least once true.. Probably I should change the place for that function.

Comment: Try ref?.child("service").child("scooters").observeSingleEvent(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

Answer (score 0):

When the user hits the cancel button, your code only changes the state and the userKey but it does nothing to change the feedback value that is going to come back as true. You need to add something to change the feedback:

```
ref?.child("service").child("scooters").child("\(scooterNumber!)").child("feedback").setValue(false)
```

Plus you have:

```
if feedback && skuter.userKey == self.userID{ .... }
```

Isnt `feedback` a Bool and `skuter.userKey` a String? How can a Bool && String == String ?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Setting value to false didn't change the thing because when I change it to true it starts happen the same thing. I am guessing that the problem is  that the `handle observer` is independent somehow. It doesn't matter if it's inside the conditional statement or not. I probably figure it out by closing everything `var userFeedback = dictionary["feedback"] as? Bool` and checking it after `skuter.userKey == self.userID`. Seems like it works for now.. need more test.